# Splunk Enterprise - Calculating best selling product & total sold products

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

New to Splunk and don't understand why this query will not work as expected, would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Expected result:

```
Country    Best Seller   Sold   Sold Total Books
Australia  Book1         23     46
UK         Book3         43     64
```

Current progress:
TOTAL SALES PER COUNTRY

```
sourcetype=access_* status=200 action=purchase 
| iplocation clientip 
| stats count(productName) as totalCount by Country
```

TOP SELLING PER COUNTRY

```
| top 1 productName by Country showperc=f countfield=sales 
| table Country,productName,sales,totalCount 
| rename productName as "Product Name", sales as Sales, totalCount as "Total Sales"
```

COMBINED QUERY (DOESN'T WORK)

```
sourcetype=access_* status=200 action=purchase 
| iplocation clientip 
| stats count(productName) as totalCount by Country 
| top 1 productName by Country showperc=f countfield=sales 
| table Country,productName,sales,totalCount 
| rename productName as "Product Name", sales as Sales, totalCount as "Total Sales"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The combined query breaks at the `top` command because the productName field no longer exists.  It was discarded by the `stats` command along with all other fields except Country and totalCount.  Here's an alternative:

````
sourcetype=access_* status=200 action=purchase 
| iplocation clientip 
```Add up the sales for each product/country```
| stats count as Sold by Country, productName 
```Get the highest and total sales for each country```
| eventstats max(Sold) as Sales, sum(Sold) as "Total Sales" by Country
```Keep only the max sales for each country```
| where Sold=Sales
| table Country,productName,Sales,"Total Sales"
| rename productName as "Product Name"
````

Comment: Hi Rich, Thank you for your help with this! Seems to be working for the most part however without the top command I see countries being repeated, I guess most importantly I am trying to understand what I did wrong but I've gathered from your example doing " stats count(productName) as totalCount" counted and then renamed it to totalCount, and I now understand you can do stats count by with multiple fields

Comment: The `eventstats` and `where` combination should do the same as `top` unless two or more products have the same sales and are highest for that country.